Kafka client SSL error stating No Algorithm found
My application was working fine but all of a sudden I am seeing a stack trace that is causing my spring boot app to crash as the Kafka producer related beans are not getting created due to SSL error. There is hardly any info I can find online about it
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing the ssl context for RestService
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.security.SslFactory.<init>(SslFactory.java:117) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.<init>(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:247) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.<init>(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:181) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.<init>(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:164) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClientFactory.newClient(SchemaRegistryClientFactory.java:36) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.configureClientProperties(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:152) ~[kafka-schema-serializer-7.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.AbstractKafkaProtobufSerializer.configure(AbstractKafkaProtobufSerializer.java:63) ~[kafka-protobuf-serializer-7.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer.configure(KafkaProtobufSerializer.java:72) ~[kafka-protobuf-serializer-7.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:387) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1.3 SSLContext not available
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.security.SslFactory.createSslContext(SslFactory.java:232) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.security.SslFactory.<init>(SslFactory.java:115) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.2.jar!/:na]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1.3 SSLContext not available
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:185) ~[na:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.security.SslFactory.createSslContext(SslFactory.java:201) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.2.jar!/:na]
    ... 67 common frames omitted

